# Pandas pd.merge results in NaN rather than the actual value

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I'm getting two different merge behaviors using pd.merge that I can't explain and I'm hoping someone can lend a hand.

**Example One**

Creating the dataframes manually results in the right merge behavior. Namely, that the Seller column has the correct value.

```
df1 = DataFrame([[1,'Dude','2016-03-07 16:21', '1e2345a6-ae7e-89e0-123d-b4567fcc8fb9']],columns=['ID','Name','Created at', 'Unit'])

df2 = DataFrame([['SellTEST','1e2345a6-ae7e-89e0-123d-b4567fcc8fb9']], columns=['Seller', 'Unit'])

merge_df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['Unit'],how='left')

print (merge_df)
```

Results:

```
   ID  Name        Created at                                  Unit    Seller
0   1  Dude  2016-03-07 16:21  1e2345a6-ae7e-89e0-123d-b4567fcc8fb9  SellTEST
```

If I read in the same data from .csv files I receive incorrect results with the merge. The Seller column now contains NaN:

**Example Two**

```
ticketdata = r'tickets3.csv'
userdata = r'users3.csv'

df1 = pd.read_csv(ticketdata)
df2 = pd.read_csv(userdata)

merge_df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['Unit'],how='left')
print (merge_df)
```

Results:

```
   ID  Name        Created at                                  Unit    Seller
0   1  Dude  2016-03-07 16:21  1e2345a6-ae7e-89e0-123d-b4567fcc8fb9     NaN
```

I've confirmed that dtypes are the same with both data sets. Everything is an Object with the exception of ID which is int64.

What am I missing?

Comment: Could you add data from your `df1` and `df2` after `read_csv`?

Answer (score 0):

Your Units in Example One are different and the result of the merge is

```
   ID  Name        Created at                                  Unit Seller
0   1  Dude  2016-03-07 16:21  7e5652a0-ae3e-11e5-820d-b3523fcc3fb4    NaN
```

(I run the code from Ex 1.) Maybe you accidentally changed Unit?

(This shouldn't be an answer but I can't comment yet.)

Comment: Thanks for taking a look - df1 had the wrong Unit value. I updated it so it should be working correctly now.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was not with my code but with the data in the CSV file. There was an errant space in the users3.csv file for the value in the Units column. Once that space was removed I was able to produce the desired results.